# How to implement an infinite list of functions in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, fibonacci

I am using a version of the Fibonacci function g where:

```
g :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
g i n  |  i==0   = 0
       |  i==1   = n
       |  i>1    = (n*( (g (i-1) n) + (g (i-2) n) ))
```

...such that g i n is the value of gi(n) and the partial definition g i is gi

I now want to define an infinite list of functions: `gs :: [ Integer -> Integer ]`, such that `(gs !! i) is gi`.

I want take 5 $ `[ g 3 | g <- gs]` to give me `[0,3,9,36,135]`.

Can anyone help me define this infinite list?

Comment: Note that your function is quite inefficient, and building a list of functions out of it will produce a list of inefficient functions. (I do wonder why you want such a list... I fear this might be an XY problem...)

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of all numbers starting at 0 using `[0 ..]`. Once you have that, it's just a matter of applying `g` to each of them.

You can do this using a list comprehension like you did in your example usage:

```
gs = [g i | i <- [0 ..]]
```

Or using map:

```
gs = map g [0 ..]
```

Comment: thanks very much. Is there any way of doing this without the use of list comprehensions and map? and filter for the matter

Comment: @bobjohnson Sure, many ways. For example you could just define your own `map` function and use that. You could even remove the function parameter and use `g` directly. And you could also get rid of `[0 ..]` by replacing the list argument with a counter that you increase instead of taking the tail of the list. It's really up to you, though the two versions I gave are definitely the simplest.

Comment: thats great thanks. how do I apply only one argument to my function g though?

Comment: @bobjohnson By not applying a second one. Like in the example with the list comprehension I apply one argument to `g` by writing `g i`. Had I written `g i 0`, that would have applied two arguments, but since I didn't add a second argument, there was only one.